# Are bitwise operations defined and portable on signed fixed-width integers?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

My understanding is that certain bitwise operations on the regular ol' short/int/long types are either implementation-dependent ( | & ~ >> ) or undefined ( << )

However, C99 introduced the fixed-width integer types and *explicitly defines them* to be two's-complement exact-bitness with no padding bits.

Does that mean that all the bitwise operations are well-defined and portable for those types among platforms that provide them?

For example, this Works on My Machine™, but is it guaranteed to work?

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  uint16_t a = 0xffff;
  int16_t b = *(int16_t*)(&a);

  printf("%" PRId16 "\n", b);

  // Prints '-1'

  b <<= 4;

  printf("%" PRId16 "\n", b); 

  // Prints '-16'

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `x << n` is undefined behavior only if `x < 0` or `n < 0` or `n >= CHAR_BIT * sizeof x`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Disagree about [is undefined behavior only if ....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61410204/are-bitwise-operations-defined-and-portable-on-signed-fixed-width-integers#comment108635044_61410204).  It is also UB with a  signed positive `x` and the shifted value is not representable in the result type.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica heh, you're right, forgot the fact that operands can have different types. Oh boy, there really is UB behind every corner...

Answer (score 5):

Using the fixed width types does not guarantee protection from [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) related to bit shifting.  Section 7.20.1.1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding exact width integer types states:

> *1* The  typedef  name `intN_t` designates  a  signed  integer  type  with  width N, no padding bits,  and  a  two’s  complement 
>   representation.   Thus, `int8_t` denotes  such  a  signed integer type
>   with a width of exactly 8 bits.
>
> *2* The  typedef  name `uintN_t` designates  an  unsigned  integer  type  with  width N and  no padding  bits.  Thus, `uint24_t` denotes 
>   such  an  unsigned  integer  type  with  a  width  of exactly 24 bits.
>
> *3* These  types  are  optional.   However,  if  an  implementation  provides  integer  types  with widths  of  8,  16,  32,  or  64  bits,
>   no  padding  bits,  and  (for  the  signed  types)  that  have  a
>   two’s complement representation, it shall define the corresponding
>   typedef names.

Nothing here mentions special treatment regarding the behavior of bit shift operations on these types.

One important aspect here is **integer promotion**.  For fixed width types that are smaller than `int`, they will first be promoted to `int` (not `int16_t` or `int32_t`) before being applied to most operands.  Then you're dealing with potential undefined behavior.

For example, assuming a 32 bit `int`, this code exhibits undefined behavior:

```
uint24_t x = 0xffffff;
uint24_t y = x << 8;
```

Because in the expression `x << 8`, the value of `x` is promoted to `int`, then the shift causes a bit to be shifted into the sign bit of that value.